# Backup strategy for redirects

Tags: redirect, solr

We are in transition mode with our website. As a part of this we have both the legacy and Sitecore sites running side by side. As we move pages into Sitecore, we create a mapping for each page so that there is a old URL to new URL mapping. This mapping is stored in Sitecore and we use Solr to decide on incoming requests how to reroute the traffic - legacy or Sitecore.

We had an incident where Solr went down and this functionality stopped working. There are about 100K entries in this mapping right now and as a result without Solr it would be hard to get this working due to the sheer number of calls it gets every hour. I'm looking for suggestions for a backup system where the redirections will work if Solr goes down.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that we have used is used Redis to map url parameters to solr fq's. You can likely do something similar to map urls to the appropriate destination. We have found Redis to be very stable and very fast.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I'll look into Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Any system you use could have a drawback on becoming unavailable. Apache Solr is typically very reliable, but why not ensure you have backups and high availability on your Apache Solr deployment? You can take a look at Apache Solr cloud for setting up high availability and use the backups API. Alternatively, you can use a [Solr-as-a-Service](https://www.searchstax.com/) to handle that for you.